# Installing LLVM libraries along with Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode6, llvm

So I just installed Xcode on my Mac and now I would like to install LLVM as well in order to play around a bit with LLVM itself. Currently the compiler can (obviously) not find the required header files. So what is the best way to install LLVM if you already have clang, packed with Xcode, on your system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do not need to read LLVM *implementation* source code(such as in `lib`/`tools` directories) and might only play with `libclang`, perhaps using `homebrew` is enough for you.

```
brew install --with-clang --with-lld --with-python --HEAD llvm
```

Next you need to set `PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For me,

```
# export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH
# export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(llvm-config --includedir):$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH 
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(llvm-config --libdir):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You might configure the above information in your LLVM derived project with XCode.

However if you are also interested in `Compiler-RT`, `Clang-Tools-Extra`(see [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#svn)) you probably have to make LLVM as your XCode project (download from that page or via SVN as said in [Getting Started with the LLVM System](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html)). After putting the sub-projects in *proper* directories, you can use XCode generator from CMake, the typical usage is:

```
cd YOUR_LLVM_SRC_ROOT
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Xcode ..
```

Use XCode to open the project file *XXX.xcodeproj* and it should build the project.

Comment: Could you explain the arguments you used to install install `llvm` via homebrew?

Comment: @ABot It's very intuitive and you can use `brew options llvm` for details.

Comment: A typo here: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` the first colon should be =

Comment: `brew install --with-clang --with-lld --with-python --HEAD llvm` doesn't work now (in June 2020) on my Macbook Pro with MacOS Mojave and Homebrew 2.4.0. `brew options llvm` also doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `brew install --with-clang --with-lld --with-python --HEAD llvm` as suggested in the other answer, but it gave me an error:

```
Error: invalid option: --with-clang
```

`brew options llvm` also showed nothing.

Then I found [another page](https://medium.com/@tapanprakasht/how-to-setup-xcode-swift-project-to-use-llvm-c-apis-3ccbf081d002) that suggests the simple

```
brew install llvm
```

This worked for me. It is with homebrew 2.4.0, on MacOS Mojave.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run (replace <your_username> with your username):

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/<your_username>/.bash_profile
```

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
```

Comment: usually you should use `brew info llvm` to check available options first :)