# Link a "toy" OS using llvm/clang

Tags: macos, linker, clang, llvm, linker-scripts

Is it possible (within reason) to build a "toy" OS on a mac using llmv/clang (and the other "normal" build tools)?  By "toy" OS, I mean the simple, "Hello, World" examples found on OSDev (http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) and x86 Bare Metal (https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples).

My main problem is I can't figure out how to specify precisely where the linker should place the code (i.e., that the starting point should be 0x7c00, that bytes 510 and 511 need to be 0xaa55, etc.).

Comment: Are you doing this OS development on OS/X or some other operating system like Linux or Windows?

Comment: OS/X.  (I would like to play around with these examples on my Mac using the "normal" build tools.)

Comment: I have put the tag `osx` on the question. The Apple versions of clang/llvm are bastardized and don't do _ELF_ and don't understand traditional GNU LD linker scripts just MACHO32/64.

Comment: I haven't looked into it; but, I'm guessing I can figure out how to deal with MACHO32/64 if I can figure out how to link the final binary image.

Comment: The problem is that the linker that comes with OSX doesn't have the same control as GNU LD, doesn't support LD linker scripts etc. It is pretty limited and was really only designed to deal with MACHO objects and executables. I'd build a GCC cross compiler (and binutils) and use tools that will work.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :)  I've heard it is easier to install a Linux VM than to actually build a cross compiler/toolchain on MacOS.

Answer (score 4):

I would say yes it is possible within reason, at least if you consider waiting for a build of lld (and its dependency llvm) reasonable. Instructions to build lld can be found on their [website](https://lld.llvm.org/#build) or as part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28208691/3140187) answer.

Compiling and linking for a different target than the host is relatively easy with clang. You just have to set a target, for example `-target i386-none-elf` for an ELF binary. Cross-compilation using clang is explained in more detail [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).

As for macOS, as Micheal Petch noted, you have to use another linker than the standard ld installed. You could in theory install binutils to get an ELF ld but then you have to compile it yourself to set the target. My recommendation is to use lld which can target many architectures without the need to recompile.

With clang and a lld in place we can compile sources with

```
clang -c -o file.o file.c -target i386-none-elf # freestanding flags omitted
```

and then link them with

```
clang -o kernel.bin file.o -target i386-linux-elf -nostdlib -Wl,linkerscript.ld -fuse-ld=lld
```

Note that for linking I am using `i386-linux-elf` because there is a bug in clang where they just forward their input to `gcc`. But when using `-nostdlib` it is essentially the same.

If you want to see a complete example ready to build, you can take a look at https://github.com/Henje/x86-Toy-OS.