# LLVM V7.0.0 MacOS Errors linking with Module::dump()

Tags: makefile, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

I migrated from OpenSuse LLVM(3.9) development environment to MacOS High Sierra. I'm trying to generate LLVM IR for a C-like language. Following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203937/installing-llvm-libraries-along-with-xcode), I installed the latest LLVM 7.0.0 with brew.
My problem is the following makefile (with -ll changed to -lfl) works on OpenSuse without a hitch  but fails with the error shown on MacOs.

```
_OBJS      = reference_table.o symbol_table.o function.o log_expr.o expr.o decl.o statement.o translation.o 
_COMMON    = common.h
LLVMCONFIG = llvm-config
CPPFLAGS   = -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include `$(LLVMCONFIG) --cxxflags` -std=c++11 -g 

LDFLAGS    = -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib `$(LLVMCONFIG) --ldflags`  
LIBS       = -v `$(LLVMCONFIG) --libs` `$(LLVMCONFIG) --system-libs` -lm   -lpthread -ldl 
OBJS       = $(patsubst %,tree/%,$(_OBJS))
COMMON     = $(patsubst %,tree/%,$(_COMMON))
OBJS      += c.tab.o c.lex.o cc.o

cc:  $(OBJS)
    clang++  $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)   -o $@

%.o: %.cpp 
    clang++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@


c.tab.cpp c.tab.hpp: c.y $(COMMON) defines.h
    bison -o c.tab.cpp -d c.y

c.lex.cpp: c.l c.tab.hpp 
    flex -o c.lex.cpp -l c.l

clean:
    rm -f c.tab.cpp c.tab.hpp c.lex.cpp cc c.output tree/*.o *.ll *.o
```

Error:

```
clang version 7.0.0 (https://llvm.org/git/clang.git 6efe17611a988cf2f4a78ab34b04f24ea7fc7dd9) (https://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 788c75b81c842cf8017f163a6e9433a40163084e)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-788c75b/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -o cc -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-788c75b/lib tree/reference_table.o tree/symbol_table.o tree/function.o tree/log_expr.o tree/expr.o tree/decl.o tree/statement.o tree/translation.o c.tab.o c.lex.o cc.o -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMPasses -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMSymbolize -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF -lLLVMMIRParser -lLLVMFuzzMutate -lLLVMCoverage -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMDlltoolDriver -lLLVMOrcJIT -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMLanaiDisassembler -lLLVMLanaiCodeGen -lLLVMLanaiAsmParser -lLLVMLanaiDesc -lLLVMLanaiAsmPrinter -lLLVMLanaiInfo -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMBPFDisassembler -lLLVMBPFCodeGen -lLLVMBPFAsmParser -lLLVMBPFDesc -lLLVMBPFInfo -lLLVMBPFAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMUtils -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMObjectYAML -lLLVMLibDriver -lLLVMOption -lLLVMWindowsManifest -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMGlobalISel -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMCoroutines -lLLVMipo -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAggressiveInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMMC -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView -lLLVMDebugInfoMSF -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMCore -lLLVMBinaryFormat -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMDemangle -lz -lcurses -lm -lxml2 -lm -lpthread -ldl -lc++ -lSystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-788c75b/lib/clang/7.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "llvm::Type::dump() const", referenced from:
      assignmentExpr::codeGen() in expr.o
  "llvm::Module::dump() const", referenced from:
      translationUnit::startCodeGen(translationUnit*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in translation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cc] Error 1
```

Furthermore if I replace the Module->dump(), Type->dump() calls with the their definitions (Module-> print(dbgs(), nullptr)), it compiles and works fine.

These dump functions are shown in 7.0.0 [reference](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#acf2ab2f5fc12e938c8397375d29a580f) .
I think I might be doing something wrong with something trivial like the makefile ordering, but so far I am not able to progress since a day.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: well it isn't finding Module->dump() you can do `nm -a objectThatYouThinkDefinesThat | c++filt | grep dump` to see if it is in fact in the object file that you think should define that object.. if it shows up with a `U` that means it is referenced and not defined and that it should be provided by another library

Comment: Thanks @GradyPlayer . This actually cleared up quite a few things for me. The symbols for dumps were only defined if the build was compiled with a debug flag and this might not be happening in brew. Hence the symbols were not exported to libLLVMBitWriter.a and thus the error. I have to figure out whether the debug flags are indeed passed or not.